# Filter Group on Conditional Only One Value in Different Field

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to complete a final filter on a data.frame to exclude groups, which are in this case "Insider CIK" numbers by those where the "Transaction Type" related to this Group is exclusively one of three options: "P-Purchase", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt". Combinations of these values for a Group I want to keep just the case where they're all the same.  The second piece to filter for only one entry by group works as needed.

Here is my script and a dput:

```
test12 <- test12 %>% group_by(`Insider CIK`) %>% filter(all(c("P-Purchase", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt") %in% `Transaction Type`) | n()>1)


structure(list(`Insider CIK` = c("0001418814", "0001418814", 
"0001418814"), `Insider Full Name and CIK` = c("ValueAct Holdings, L.P. (0001418814)", 
"ValueAct Holdings, L.P. (0001418814)", "ValueAct Holdings, L.P. (0001418814)"
), `Acquistion or Disposition` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"D", "-"), class = "factor"), `Transaction Date` = structure(c(18334, 
18333, 18332), class = "Date"), `Deemed Execution Date` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "Â", class = "factor"), Issuer = c("HAWAIIAN ELECTRIC INDUSTRIES INC", 
"HAWAIIAN ELECTRIC INDUSTRIES INC", "HAWAIIAN ELECTRIC INDUSTRIES INC"
), Form = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("4", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    `Transaction Type` = c("P-Purchase", "P-Purchase", "P-Purchase"
    ), `Direct or Indirect Ownership` = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("--D", "--I"), class = "factor"), `Number of Securities Transacted` = c(542252, 
    400060, 755600), `Issuer CIK` = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("0000750574", 
    "0000007431", "0000100726", "0000354707", "0000885590", "0001101215", 
    "0001137789", "0001655075", "0001739445", "0001512499", "0000874761", 
    "0001140536", "0001308161", "0001099800", "0001280776", "0001314102", 
    "0001389072", "0001642545"), class = "factor"), `Security Name` = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L), .Label = c("common stock", "Common Shares, no par value", 
    "Common Stock", "Forward Purchase Contract", "Ordinary Shares", 
    "Physically Settled Forwards", "Series A Non-Voting Convertible Preferred Stock", 
    "Class A Common Stock", "Class B Common Stock", "Deferred Stock Units", 
    "Forward purchase contract", "Ordinary Shares, nominal value $0.000304635", 
    "Ordinary Shares, nominal value $0.000304635 per share", 
    "Units", "Employee Stock Option (Right to Acquire)", "Performance Rights", 
    "Common stock", "Employee Stock Option (right to buy)", "Restricted Stock Unit", 
    "Restricted Stock Units", "Senior Convertible Preferred Stock", 
    "Stock Option (right to buy)", "Stock Option (Right to Buy)", 
    "Stock Options (Right to Buy)"), class = "factor"), `Days Since Most Recent Filing` = structure(c(0, 
    1, 2), class = "difftime", units = "days"), firstTransactionDate = structure(c(18334, 
    18334, 18334), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(`Insider CIK` = "0001418814", 
    .rows = list(1:3)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you show the expected output.  The example shows only 3 rows

Comment: Expected output in this case would be null because for the Group ID provided the transaction type is only "P-Purchase"

Comment: Do you need `test12 %>% group_by(`Insider CIK`) %>% filter(!(all(c("P-Purchase", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt") %in% `Transaction Type`) | n()>1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need the `n() == 1` condition as there is no chance of having nore than one `Transaction Type` per row

```
library(dplyr)
test12 %>% 
      group_by(`Insider CIK`) %>%
      filter(all(c("P-Purchase", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt") %in% `Transaction Type`))
```

Or if the OP wanted the `n() == 1` it would be `|`

```
test12 %>% 
      group_by(`Insider CIK`) %>%
      filter(all(c("P-Purchase", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt") %in% `Transaction Type`) |n() == 1)
```

Comment: I want to retain the existing condition that for Group ID's where there is only one entry I want those dropped as well.

Comment: @js80 do you need `filter(all(c("P-Purchase", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt") %in% `Transaction Type`) |n_distinct(`Transaction Type`) == 1)

Comment: I don't think the n_distinct adjustment relative to Transaction Type is needed.  It would work but I'd like to tie this condition to the number of observations by CIK number being 1. I.e only one purchase or sale not qualifying. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @js80 I didn't get that logic correctly.  What I understand is that if you have  all the three elements `"P-Purchase", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt"` present in a group, then filter it.  Second part with `n() > 1` is not clear

Comment: @js80 lets say if you have group with Transactiion Type having only 'P-Purchase and there are 3 rows i.e. duplicates.  It would still fail with the first condition

Comment: Sorry here is the logic: condition 1 if for a given CIK number the Transaction Types are exclusively one of those three options - drop it from the data.frame.  At the same time if there is only one entry for a given CIK Number drop it as well.

Comment: @js80 the first condition will get dropped from the `all` case,  second condition i understand is n() == 1, that won't happen when the first condition is TRUE

Comment: Understood but I'm try to look at two potential options.  If you're saying I don't need the second because the first accomplishes it then I should think about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212658/discussion-between-js80-and-akrun).

Comment: @js80 COnsider this example. `df1 <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:2, c(4, 1)), val = c('a', 'b', c', 'a', 'b'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and now we are `filter`ing only if all the 'a', 'b', 'c' are present, `df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(all(c('a', 'b', 'c) %in% val))`